# Getting a string from a resource file in an untyped manner

Tags: c#, .net, resources, localization, resx

I'm working on an ASP.Net project which has all of its translations in a Translations.resx file. Is there an easy way to get a translated string in an untyped manner?

I don't want to do

```
Translations.TranslateThisKey
```

but rather something like

```
Translations["TranslateThisKey"]
```

I need this because the key is a code coming from an external resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var Translations = new ResourceManager("MyResources", 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false, true)
        .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
        .Where(e => e.Value is string)
        .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => (string) e.Value);

var result = Translations["TranslateThisKey"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("NAME_OF_YOUR_STRING_IN_RESX_FILE")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx)